# sdkman and $PATH in Linux

Tags: java, version, sdkman

After installing sdkman and let it install java temurin 8 and 17 and setting use to java 8, `$JAVA_HOME` nicely pointed to the current candidate.

But `$PATH` and `java -version` still point to the original `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin`. Do I have to manually modify `$PATH`, each time I change the current java version?

I changed the 'use' version, and `$JAVA_HOME` changed appropriately, but `$PATH` and `java -version` did not change.

Comment: Run commands and check (1) `javac -version` -> **javac 17.0.5** 
(2) `java -version` -> **
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8, mixed mode, sharing)**
(3) `which java` -> **/home/YourUserName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java**, if not, Your Java Is not come from SDKMAN, remove It. maybe `sudo apt remove XXX`

Comment: Same problem here. I have a clean Ubuntu installation. Just like you, my JAVA_HOME was set but my PATH is not modified, so e.g. java -version reports that 'java' is not found.